# ClassVisitor does not give the private methods with content of Lambda expression

Tags: java-bytecode-asm

This ClassVisitor never shows the generated private methods that hold the content of Lambda expressions.

The ClassVisitor is used like this (i cut the function, i just want to know why the ClassVisitor does not visit the `private void lambda`, it is working with the other methods like charm).

```
ClassReader classReader = new ClassReader(className);
ClassWriter classWriter = new ClassWriter(4);

CustomClassVisitor customClassVisitor = new CustomClassVisitor(classWriter);

classReader.accept(customClassVisitor,0);

modifiedClass = classWriter.toByteArray();
```

The ClassVisitor:

```
import org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor;
import org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter;
import org.objectweb.asm.MethodVisitor;

import static org.objectweb.asm.Opcodes.ASM7;

public class CustomClassVisitor extends ClassVisitor {

    public CustomClassVisitor(ClassWriter classWriter) {

        super(ASM7, classWriter);
    }

    public MethodVisitor visitMethod(
            int access,
            String name,
            String desc,
            String signature,
            String[] exceptions) {

            final MethodVisitor methodVisitor = cv.visitMethod(access, name, desc, signature, exceptions);

            return methodVisitor;       
    }
}
```

They are in bytecode:

```
  private void lambda$main$0(java.lang.Integer) 
    descriptor: (Ljava/lang/Integer;)V
    flags: (0x1002) ACC_PRIVATE, ACC_SYNTHETIC
    Code:
      stack=3, locals=2, args_size=2
         0: aload_0
         1: bipush        100
         3: aload_1
         4: invokevirtual #11                 // Method java/lang/Integer.intValue:()I
         7: invokevirtual #4                  // Method wait:(II)V
        10: return
      LineNumberTable:
        line 45: 0
        line 46: 10
      LocalVariableTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
            0      11     0  this   Lorg/Lambda;
            0      11     1  elem   Ljava/lang/Integer;
```

How could i see this method in ASM ClassVisitor? Is there an extra parameter? ClassWriter is in mode 4.

Comment: What exactly do you expect? You `CustomClassVisitor` is not doing anything.

Comment: i edited the question

Comment: There’s still no explanation of how you come to the conclusion that the method was not visited. Your visitor has no visible effect. So what do you expect? And what is “ClassWriter is in mode 4” supposed to mean? There is no “mode 4” in that API.